# Win32 API: transparency doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, transparency

I wrote a simple program; it's made of a main window and TextBox window above it. TextBox is 50% transparent. When TextBox gets a message, it draws a blue line on the main window.

The problem is that "transparent" actually is not transparent at all. If the blue line crosses a text in TextBox, the text just erased, despite the fact that the text is above. And vice versa: if I start typing, a part of the line in a row of a text just disappears instead of shine through. 
Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT 101

void DrawInWindow(HWND hWndToPaint){
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWndToPaint);
    if(!hdc)printf("Invalid handle\n");
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,5,RGB(0, 0, 255));
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
    static float x=620, y=1, tg=0.5, ctg=2;
    static int Xone = 1, Yone = 1;//depending on later recalculation this may become negative
    MoveToEx(hdc,(int)x,(int)y,NULL);
    if(tg<1){
        y+=tg;
        x+=Xone;
    }else{
        y+=Yone;
        x+=ctg;
    }
    if(!LineTo(hdc, (int)x, (int)y) )printf("There are paint problem\n");
    ReleaseDC(hWndToPaint,hdc);
    //Now recalculate direction
    RECT WndRect;
    GetClientRect(hWndToPaint,&WndRect);
    if(x>=WndRect.right){
        if(ctg>0)ctg*=-1;//make negative
        Xone=-1;
    }
    if(x<=WndRect.left){
        if(ctg<0)ctg*=-1;//make positive
        Xone=1;
    }
    if(y>=WndRect.bottom){
        if(tg>0)tg*=-1;//make negative
        Yone=-1;
    }
    if(y<=WndRect.top){
        if(tg<0)tg*=-1;//make positive
        Yone=1;
    }
}

int CALLBACK EnumWindowsFunc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam){
    DrawInWindow(hWnd);
    return false;
}
void PaintInMainWnd(){
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsFunc,0L);//Getting the handle of main window to draw
}
LRESULT __stdcall MyMainCallBckProcedure( HWND window, unsigned msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp ){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if(wp == VK_ESCAPE)PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            printf("\ndestroying window\n");
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        case WM_SIZE:{
            HWND hEdit;
            RECT rcClient;

            GetClientRect(window, &rcClient);
            hEdit = GetDlgItem(window, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);
            SetWindowPos(hEdit, NULL, 0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc( window, msg, wp, lp ) ;
    }
}

WNDPROC lpEditWndProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyEditCallBckProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if( (uMsg == WM_CHAR) && (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) )
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    PaintInMainWnd();
    lpEditWndProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

bool CreateWindows(){
    const char* const myclass = "myclass";
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, MyMainCallBckProcedure,
                            0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
                            LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1),
                            0, myclass, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };
    if(RegisterClassEx(&wndclass)<0){
        printf("ERR: in registering window class\n");
        return false;
    }
    //Creating window
    HWND window = CreateWindowEx( 0, myclass, "title",
                   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                   640, 480, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0 );
    if(!window){
        printf("ERR: in creating window\n");
        return false;
    }
    ShowWindow( window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
    //creating TextBox on the window
    HFONT hfDefault;
    HWND hEdit;
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, "edit", "", 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        window, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if(hEdit == NULL){
        MessageBox(window, "Could not create edit box.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }
    hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
    //Now resize TextBox to fill whole parent window
    RECT RectSize;
    GetClientRect(window,&RectSize);
    hEdit = GetDlgItem(window,IDC_MAIN_EDIT);
    SetWindowPos(hEdit, 0,0,0,RectSize.right,RectSize.bottom,SWP_NOZORDER);
    //Let's try to catch some messages in TextBox...
    lpEditWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&MyEditCallBckProcedure);
    //Making hEdit transparent
    SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit,GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | GetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, GWL_EXSTYLE) );
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hEdit, 0, (255*50)/100, LWA_ALPHA);
    return true;
    //###
}

int main(){
    if(!CreateWindows() ){printf("Something gone wrong\n");return 1;}
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0) ){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Don't know is it important, but I should also mention, that I have tested only under Ubuntu with Wine, as my Windows is screwed up by [this bug](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-0xc0000005-when-ever-i-try-to-do-anything/568af1bf-b998-47af-a9cf-9373ae735100). Anyway, I hope the problem is not in Wine itself.
And sorry for amount of code, I really don't know what to remove to make it smaller.

Comment: `WS_EX_LAYERED`, and thus `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` and `UpdateLayeredWindow()` cannot be used with child controls prior to Windows 8.

Comment: You could try adding the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style on the parent window. Also note that layered child windows weren't supported prior to Windows 8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , @JonathanPotter [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx), `WS_EX_LAYERED` was introduced since Windows 2000, and layered windows was supported since this time.

Comment: @YagamyLight: yes, it was. But if you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) more carefully, it also says: "Windows 8: The `WS_EX_LAYERED` style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. **Previous Windows versions support `WS_EX_LAYERED` only for top-level windows.**"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, then in light of the circumstances seems my question have no a sense... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I found the workaround. I created background top level window, and made foreground window 50% trasparent. I draw the lines in background window. If the front window moved or resized, the back window reacts accordingly with help of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message, it sent on every little move/resize.

Anyway, this workaround is little dirty because of:
*Linux/wine* specific problems: 1) Display Manager do not decorate transparent window of *wine*(but this could be evaded by making second window 0% transparent) 2) Dragged window wobbling, but the second moving straight. All OS specific problem: second window is visible in the taskbar. Theoretically the last could be avoided by adding `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` to unowned window. [The quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create
>   the unowned window with the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style.

But, at least, in *wine* it doesn't work. Well, I hope this is a bug :)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT 101

HWND hBackWnd;

void DrawInWindow(HWND hWndToPaint){
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWndToPaint);
    if(!hdc)printf("Invalid handle\n");
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,5,RGB(0, 0, 255));
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
    static float x=620, y=1, tg=0.5, ctg=2;
    static int Xone = 1, Yone = 1;//depending on later recalculation this may become negative
    MoveToEx(hdc,(int)x,(int)y,NULL);
    if(tg<1){
        y+=tg;
        x+=Xone;
    }else{
        y+=Yone;
        x+=ctg;
    }
    if(!LineTo(hdc, (int)x, (int)y) )printf("There are paint problem\n");
    ReleaseDC(hWndToPaint,hdc);
    //Now recalculate direction
    RECT WndRect;
    GetClientRect(hWndToPaint,&WndRect);
    if(x>=WndRect.right){
        if(ctg>0)ctg*=-1;//make negative
        Xone=-1;
    }
    if(x<=WndRect.left){
        if(ctg<0)ctg*=-1;//make positive
        Xone=1;
    }
    if(y>=WndRect.bottom){
        if(tg>0)tg*=-1;//make negative
        Yone=-1;
    }
    if(y<=WndRect.top){
        if(tg<0)tg*=-1;//make positive
        Yone=1;
    }
}

LRESULT __stdcall MyMainCallBckProcedure( HWND window, unsigned msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp ){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if(wp == VK_ESCAPE)PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            printf("\ndestroying window\n");
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        case WM_SIZE:
            HWND hEdit;
            RECT rcClient;

            GetClientRect(window, &rcClient);
            hEdit = GetDlgItem(window, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);
            SetWindowPos(hEdit, NULL, 0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER);
            break;
        case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:{//LPARAM is a ptr to WINDOWPOS
            RECT BckWndRect;
            if(!GetWindowRect(hBackWnd, &BckWndRect) )printf("ERR: getting backwnd rectangle\n");
            bool IsRepaint;
            WINDOWPOS* pNewPos = (WINDOWPOS*)lp;
            if(BckWndRect.left+BckWndRect.right != pNewPos->cx
            || BckWndRect.top+BckWndRect.bottom != pNewPos->cy)IsRepaint = true;
            else IsRepaint = false;
            MoveWindow(hBackWnd, pNewPos->x, pNewPos->y, pNewPos->cx, pNewPos->cy, IsRepaint);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc( window, msg, wp, lp ) ;
    }
}

WNDPROC lpEditWndProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyEditCallBckProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if( (uMsg == WM_CHAR) && (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) )
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    DrawInWindow(hBackWnd);
    lpEditWndProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

bool CreateWindows(){
    //creating back window
    const char* backwnd = "backwnd";
    WNDCLASSEX backwndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, MyMainCallBckProcedure,
                            0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
                            LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1),
                            0, backwnd, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };
    if(RegisterClassEx(&backwndclass)<0){
        printf("ERR: in registering second window class\n");
        return false;
    }
    hBackWnd = CreateWindowEx( 0, backwnd, "title", WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW |
                   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                   640, 480, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0 );
    if(!hBackWnd){
        printf("ERR: in creating background window\n");
        return false;
    }
    ShowWindow( hBackWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
    //Creating front window
    const char* const frontwnd = "frontwnd";
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, MyMainCallBckProcedure,
                            0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
                            LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1),
                            0, frontwnd, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };
    if(RegisterClassEx(&wndclass)<0){
        printf("ERR: in registering foreground window class\n");
        return false;
    }
    HWND window = CreateWindowEx( 0, frontwnd, "title",
                   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                   640, 480, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0 );
    if(!window){
        printf("ERR: in creating foreground window\n");
        return false;
    }
    ShowWindow( window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
    //creating textbox
    HWND hEdit = CreateWindowEx( 0, "edit", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL 
                                | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640,
                                480, window, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(0), 0 );
    HFONT hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
    //Let's try to catch some messages in TextBox...
    lpEditWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&MyEditCallBckProcedure);
    //Making foreground window transparent
    SetWindowLongPtr(window,GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | GetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_EXSTYLE) );
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, 0, (255*50)/100, LWA_ALPHA);
    return true;
    //###
}

int main(){
    if(!CreateWindows() ){printf("Something gone wrong\n");return 1;}
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0) ){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```